# Importing Python modules from different levels of hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

Within the top level of my git repository, I have the following file structure:

```
miscellaneous Dockerfiles, readme, etc
Code/
    training.py
    data/
        generate.py
        tasksets.py
```

Sometimes I want to import the `generate` module from within the `tasksets` module when I run the `tasksets` module as a script, so `tasksets` includes the following import:

```
import generate
```

Other times I want to import the `tasksets` module from within the `training` module, so `training` contains the following import:

```
import tasksets
```

However, this setup is giving me problems. `tasksets` can import `generate` fine when I run `tasksets` as a script, but throws an error if I import `tasksets` inside `training` when I run `training` as a script (I think because `training` can't find `generate` as a script within the default path). I've tried looking at all sorts of other StackOverflow questions and answers, using `__init__.py` files, relative imports, etc. Currently, my workaround is to use the following lines inside `tasksets`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": import generate
else: from data import generate
```

But this doesn't feel right (and my IDE don't like it neither). Please can someone explain how to use the right assortment of `__init__.py` files and import statements such that I can import `generate` when running `tasksets` as a script, and also import `tasksets` when running `training` as a script?

Comment: Can't you just place an empty `__init__.py` in the `data/` directory. Then you can write `from data import generate` in your `training.py` and in `tasksets.py` you have `from . import generate`. Could this be a solution?

Comment: @be-ndee I just tried this. I replaced my workaround in `tasksets.py` with `from . import generate`, added the empty `__init__.py` file in the `data/` directory, and ran `tasksets` as a script, and got the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'generate'`

Answer (score 5):

You better use a classical Python module / package architecture.

```
projectname/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    data/
        __init__.py
        generate.py
        tasksets.py
```

To use your app, go into `projectname/../` directory (one level upper `projectname/`) and run `python -m projectname`. This will execute `projectname/__main__.py`.

---

In `__main__.py` you will write something like:

```
from projectname.data import generate
from projectname.data import tasksets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate.foo()
    tasksets.bar()
```

1. You will use absolute import path (starting by your module name and a dot, `projectname.`)
2. You will import your submodules out of the `if __name__ == '__main__'`
3. `__main__.py` will be the only entry-point of your app/script.

In any other file, you will use the same syntax and paths to import other modules:

`data/generate.py`:

```
from projectname.data import tasksets

def foo():
    print('SPAM!')
    tasksets.bar()
```

---

*Something I don't really enjoy, but I'm not sure any PEP deny it,*

In your `projectname/__init__.py` file you can write:

```
from projectname.data import generate
from projectname.data import tasksets
```

So your two submodules will be imported into your main scope `__init__.py`, so you are able to import the submodules from this scope, like

`data/generate.py`:

```
from projectname import generate
```

But again, I don't really enjoy this way of doing (because *Explicit is better than implicit.*)

---

*Last but not least,*

- You can also use `python projectname/__main__.py` command, but I still recommend `python -m projectname`
- You can create a `setup.py` file using [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to "install" your app on your system and simply run `projectname` command to run it.

Comment: Thank you @Arount for the answer! Please could you clarify, in your 2nd suggestion, which of the `__init__,py`s should `from projectname.data import generate` and `from projectname.data import tasksets` go into? The one in the `data` folder? (Knowing what to put in which `__init__.py` is something that has confused me a fair bit in other explanations as well)

Comment: Also I agree that I want to avoid the `*` wildcard imports, but the alternate version putting explicit imports in the `__init__.py` appeals to me because I would ideally like to maintain my current file structure because it otherwise suits my project well (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: @JakeLevi I updated the `projectname/__init__.py` part to make it more obvious. Also, if you really want to keep your current files naming, you can rename `__main__.py` into `training.py`, but your directory name (in your example `Code`) will still be used as package name (`from Code.data import ...`) and you will need to run your code with `python -m Code.training`. I don't think it's the best because it's very puzzling, but it should be running.