# Python ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'custom'

Tags: python, module

I am running into an error that I am struggling to debug and am very confused.

I have a folder structure like this:

```
|_all_tests.py
|_main.py
|_pitches
  |__zones.py
  |__pitches.py
  |__errors.py
```

In zones I import errors, and when I run the zones file there are no errors. However, I import zones from main, and when I import zones from main I get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'errors'.

I am confused why this is the case. When I run zones I get no errors, but when I import zones (and hence run the code) I get this ModuleNotFoundError... can someone help explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `zones.py` directly, python searches for modules relative to the address `zones.py` is in, therefore, it can find `errors` as it is in the same directory.

However, when you run `main.py`, python starts looking for the modules you import inside the folder `main.py` is in, even if your import line is inside another file in another directory. If you plan to run `main.py`, then you should change your import lines to be relative to your project root address. For example, change `import errors` in `zones.py` to `import pitches.errors`.

You should also add a `__init__.py` file to your pitches folder in this case. It can be empty.

Comment: this fixes everything - thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 2):

since the way you import them is important, look at [Importing Python modules from different levels of hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154159/importing-python-modules-from-different-levels-of-hierarchy) . it might help

Answer (score 1):

Add to /pitches folder the file __ init __.py to indicate python that the folder is a package.